# change position of html element with js without css

Tags: javascript, html

I am new with js,
I want to change the position of HTML element with javascript without CSS.
is this possible without CSS?....

```
<button>Change left and top position </button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property:

> The `HTMLElement.style` property is used to get as well as set the inline style of an element. When getting, it returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object that contains a list of all styles properties for that element with values assigned for the attributes that are defined in the element's inline style attribute.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.style.position = "absolute";
btn.style.left = "50px";
btn.style.top = "20px";
```

```html
<button>Change left and top position </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write to `HTMLElement.style` like

```
element.style.left = '10px'
element.style.top = '20px'
```

Comment: i want to create a variable that stores the element position of the HTML element, then use that variable to change position .... is this possible with object?....

Comment: @D.R. where's the problem? can you elaborate more?

Comment: I want to change the position at different co-ordinates after user interaction with the page, So i have to use HTML.style method 3 times for change position every 1 time...

Comment: I want some short object like a thing to change with a small change in property....

Comment: @D.R. you may use some type of template engine, but it would probably just wrap these call. can you post your current code? and desired behavior (in image or any form)